# eslint SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression flags

Tags: reactjs, jenkins

Tengo un problema a la hora de desplegar en jenkins.

Cuando intento desplegar me muestra el siguiente error:

```
[32mInstall complete.
[39m(node:41590) [DEP0026] DeprecationWarning: util.print is deprecated. Use console.log instead.
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/DEV/node_modules/eslint/lib/source-code/source-code.js:426
        return /\s/u.test(text.replace(/\/\*.*?\*\//gus, ""));
                                       ^

SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression flags
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:599:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/DEV/node_modules/eslint/lib/source-code/index.js:4:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! designer-app@0.1.0 build: `fontello-cli install --config ./src/styles/components/icons/config.json --css  ./src/styles/components/icons/css --font  ./src/styles/components/icons/font && mkdir -p ./build && babel ./src/service-worker-designer.js --out-file ./build/service-worker-designer.js && react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the designer-app@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Por lo que he estado mirando se ve que es un problema de la versión de [eslint](https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/eslint/eslint/12493/546926382).

¿Alguien sabría decirme exactamente que hacer para solucionarlo y poder desplegar en jenkins?

**EDIT**

El problema estaba en que en jenkins estaba utilizando la versión 8.9.0 y en mi pc la versión 8.10.0. Se ve que la versión 8.9.0 no soporta eslint 6.6.0. He ido a Global Tool Configuration y he cambiado la versión de node a la misma que utilizo en mi pc. He vuelto a desplegar y no ha dado ningún problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu regex `/\/\*.*?\*\//gus`, la `u` y `s` son flags soportados solo por es9 (ECMA2018), especificación que empezó a ser implementada [en versiones 4.x](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/9893) de `eslint` (Al día de hoy ya van en la [6.6.0](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/releases)).
Creo que tu mejor opción es actualizar tu versión de `eslint` y si algún otro módulo tiene como dependencia una versión antigua de `eslint`, actualiza también ese módulo.

Comment: Lo he solucionado!!! Edito la pregunta para que veas como lo he hecho.